# XAMPP won't start Apache - PID2964

Tags: apache, xampp

I've tried numerous times to start Apache, but this is the error it gives me on XAMPP control panel:

```
Problem detected!
12:41:09  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 2964!
12:41:09  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
12:41:09  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
12:41:09  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
12:41:10  [Apache]  Problem detected!
12:41:10  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 2964!
12:41:10  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
12:41:10  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
12:41:10  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I've gone to skype and made it not use ports 80 and 443 for connection but it still won't start, even if I close skype.

Comment: what are you working on? Linux? Windows? either way you need to check what is the process with PID 2964 . Linux => ps -aux . Windows => check the task manager.  And gie us more details.

Comment: I checked task manager on windows and it said I already had an apache server running, so I closed it and started another one. Thanks!